# PHP form validation for user registration

Tags: php, validation

### Add User

* required field

```
 <label for="firstname"> First Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label for="Password">Password</label>
  <input type="text" name="Password">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <label for="usertype">User Type</label>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <div>
    <label for="Admin" class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="user" id="Admin" value="Admin">Admin</label>
  <label for="Member" class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="user"id="Member" value="Member">Member</label>
  <label for="Guest" class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="user" id="Guest" value="Guest">Guest</label>
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <label for="Status">Status</label>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
  <div>
    <label for="Active" class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="Status" id="Active" value="Active">Active</label>
  <label for="Inactive" class="radio-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="Status" id="Inactive" value="Inactive">Inactive</label></div>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">  
</form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
      </section>
    </body>
```

```
<?php
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
$Status=$_POST['Status'];


//database connect
$conn = mysqli_connect($localhost, $root,$"", $usert);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die('Connection Failed:'.$conn>'connect-error');
}
else{
    $stmt=$conn->prepare("insert into user(firstname,lastname,email,Password,user,Status)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssii',$firstname,$lastname,$email,$Password,$user,$Status);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo"Success!";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();}
?>
```

hi, trying to make a simple form with PHP validation for user registration. When I am giving the input value is not working. I can't understand the error .please help! I am new to PHP. Please let me know the correction.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unqx4.png)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. have added the codes now

Comment: The code you shared doesn't define `$nameErr`, ie. your input validation isn't included what you show, and therefore we have no idea why you get the "required field" notice. _Is that the error, or are there other errors?_ (It looks like there would be a bunch. Add them all to your question -- as text.)

Comment: I wanted to add an error class. If the field is blank it will show the error text. Unfortunately, none of this is working properly!

Comment: We wouldn't know why without seeing the relevant code. Do note that you can't just guess at how stuff might work and expect it to work. Read good tutorials and [study the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). I suggest starting with the very basics and the difference between a variable (that needs to be assigned) and a string literal; judging by `$conn = mysqli_connect($localhost, $root,$"", $usert);`. And _please ensure that your environment is set to display all errors!!_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go through these PHP documentations and get yourself familiar with how the database connection, queries etc work:

- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Looking at your code quickly, here are few places to start with:

a) The things like database credentials - you should define these, those should not come through PHP forms

b) Make sure on the variable names etc. For example you've used `$user` at the top and later used `$username`.

Start here:

a) Just write this much of code in a file and make sure database is connected properly:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); // write actual database credentials and database name

if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
} else {
  echo "Database connected properly";
}
```

b) Next, on form submission page just see first if you are getting the values from form submission:

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I once thought about the "user section" but did not understand the issue properly. I will check those resources. can you give me few more corrections please!

Answer (score -1):

You haven't declared your DB credentials, it is just using random variables.

Replace the variables in your mysqli_connect() function with actual values/correct variables

Answer (score -1):

you should use PDO for connect your php code to databes.read this document for help:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp